# Can't pass variable value from firebase firestore to another class SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

So I have this function in class `Functions` :

```
struct Prices {
      var standardPrice: Int!

}

// FUNC PRICING

class Functions {
    private var PricingRef: CollectionReference!
    var price = Prices()

func getPrice() -> Prices {

        PricingRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("ProductXYZ")

        PricingRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                debugPrint("Error fetching data \(err)")
            }
            else {
                guard let snap = snapshot else { return }
                for document in snap.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let std = data["standard"] as! String
                    self.price.standardPrice = Int(std)!
                    print(self.price.standardPrice!) // This print the intended result

                }

            }
        }
        return price
    }
}
```

Then I want to pass the `standardPrice` value to this class, called `PriceList` :

```
class PriceList: UITableViewController {
     var price = Prices()
     var newStandardPrice = 0

func Price() {
        price = Functions().getPrice()
        newStandardPrice = price.standardPrice // always error with value nil
}
```

I always have that error where `newStandardPrice` is nil.
but the `print(self.price.standardPrice!)` shows number of result I want.
So as far as I know, the problem here is because it takes time for the firebase firestore to get the data from database.
How do I get the value of `standardPrice` after its assigned with the new price from firebase database?

Any help will be appreciated

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use completion handler because its async function

```
func getPrice(completion:@escaping (Prices?,Error?)-> Void)  {

        PricingRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("ProductXYZ")

        PricingRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                debugPrint("Error fetching data \(err)")
                 completion(nil,err)
            }
            else {
                guard let snap = snapshot else { return }
                for document in snap.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let std = data["standard"] as! String
                    self.price.standardPrice = Int(std)!
                    print(self.price.standardPrice!) // This print the intended result
                    completion(self.price.standardPrice,nil)

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

How to use

```
Functions().getPrice { (price, error) in

        if let err = error {
            // do something if you get error
        } else if let getPrice = price {
            // use price
           self.price = getPriice
        }
```

Comment: hey man thanks for answering, however `completion(self.price.standardPrice,nil)` shows error `Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Prices?'`
Do I still need the ` -> Prices ` at the end of func `getPrice()` ?

Comment: Give it self.price ... instead of self.price.standardPrice

Comment: hey man all good! it works bro, you're the real MVP here. thanks a lot man